# Alphabetic Regex in HTML5

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I'm really new to regex but I need to find a way to add a filter to a HTML5 form:

```html
<input type="text" required="true" name="firstname" pattern="WHAT DO I PUT HERE">
```

Could anyone help me with what to put in the pattern attribute, for example

Accepted:

- `John`
- `Frank`

Not accepted:

- `Ke$ha`
- `B0B`

(Only alphabetic characters are accepted.)

Comment: if this post is solved, can you kindly check the answer that solved it.

Comment: I tried before but it said please wait 3 minutes, I have now though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some nice examples: http://html5pattern.com/

In your case I would use:

```
[a-zA-Z]+
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, How would I go about making it only accept at least 3 letters and max 20 letters?

Comment: Off the top of my head it's something like: [a-zA-Z]{3,20} It might be helpful to take a look at a regex primer, these expressions are fairly portable across languages.

Comment: You know, you can show your appreciation to this guy by voting his answer up and accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't too specific, but I'll assume you want to rule out nonalphabetic characters.

The pattern for non-empty alphabetic-only word is

```
[a-zA-Z]+
```

where `a-z` stands for the range of lowercase letters, `A-Z` for the range of uppercase letter. `[a-zA-Z]` then means any letter and `+` means at least one.

Answer (score 0):

```
pattern="[A-Za-z ]"
```

to allow only alphabetic characters and spaces